# Where is PORTB defined?

Tags: pins, port-mapping

On Arduino I can set digital pins by setting special variables PORTB and PORTD (or maybe they are not variables?). Where are those variables defined? I grepped /usr/share/arduino, but found nothing.

```
grep -r 'PORTB' /usr/share/arduino/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PORTB is defined by the "toolchain". It is not defined by Arduino.
For instance in my setup the Arduino Uno uses "toolchain" avr-gcc\4.9.2-amtel3.5.3-arduino2\avr.

If you grep that folder (location dependent on tool and installation options) you will find a file called `iom328p.h` that defines

```
#define PORTB _SFR_IO8(0x05)
```

This is a mapping to a physical address of the cpu.

Comment: Thank you. And how does this file gets included when my program is compiled and linked? Is it included by Arduino.h?

Comment: Arduino.h includes avr/io.h, which in turn includes the ioXXX.h file relevant to your specific MCU.

Answer (score -1):

> . Where are those variables defined?

In the device header file. Like other device specific macros.