# Where is CLKPR located on Ubuntu 16.04 with Arduino 1.8.3

Tags: frequency, avr-toolchain

I would like to see the definition of CLKPR. I guess that similarly to PORTB and other registers, it should be defined by the toolchain? (see [Where is PORTB defined?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/34639/where-is-portb-defined) )

- Am I right?
- Where should I look for this toolchain on Ubuntu 16.04? I tried *locate* and *find* commands in terminal with various strings relating to the toolchain expected path / files, but could not find it (tips and tricks on how I may look for such paths in the future would be welcome ;) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` is the command you want:

```
foo@bar:~/arduino-1.8.2$ grep -r CLKPR .
Binary file ./hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib/avr35/crtattiny167.o matches
Binary file ./hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib/avr35/crtat90usb82.o matches
Binary file ./hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib/avr35/crtatmega8u2.o matches
...
Binary file ./hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib/avr5/crtat90pwm161.o matches
Binary file ./hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib/avr5/crtatmega649p.o matches
Binary file ./hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib/avr5/crtatmega168pa.o matches
./hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/avr/io90pwm216.h:#define CLKPR   _SFR_MEM8(0x61)
./hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/avr/iom329.h:#define CLKPR   _SFR_MEM8(0x61)
./hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/avr/iom165p.h:#define CLKPR   _SFR_MEM8(0x61)
...
./hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/avr/iom48p.h:#define CLKPR _SFR_MEM8(0x61)
./hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/avr/iom644pa.h:#define CLKPR _SFR_MEM8(0x61)
./hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/avr/ioa6289.h:#define CLKPR _SFR_IO8(0x3C)
./hardware/arduino/avr/bootloaders/caterina-Arduino_Robot/Caterina.h:       #define CPU_PRESCALE(n) (CLKPR = 0x80, CLKPR = (n))
./hardware/arduino/avr/bootloaders/caterina-LilyPadUSB/Caterina.h:      #define CPU_PRESCALE(n) (CLKPR = 0x80, CLKPR = (n))
./hardware/arduino/avr/bootloaders/caterina/Caterina.h:     #define CPU_PRESCALE(n) (CLKPR = 0x80, CLKPR = (n))
```

So it's defined in the IO header for the chip you are using (`hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/avr/io[chip].h`). So for the '328p that's `hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/avr/iom328p.h`.

Comment: This is great, thank you! A couple of noobs questions: -1: this is not the toolchain, isn t it? -2: so for an Arduino Mega 1280, I should look at iom1280.h isn t it? But there is no CLKPR in it (grep CLKPR iom1280.h returns nothing while in the right folder), while I am quite sure it is also called CLKPR for the 1280 (I checked in the datasheet). Where is CLKPR defined for the Mega then?

Comment: Yes, that is the toolchain. It will be in that file, but it may be called something else. Edit the file and browse through it.

Comment: `iom1280.h` includes the standard file `iomxx0_1.h`.  That defines `CLKPR` as `_SFR_MEM8(0x61)`.